# How to make this kind of rule in latex?

Tags: header-footer, rules

[image]

How can I make this kind of rule? I’ve tried, but the lighter one doesn,t align on top. Thanks in advance.

This is the code I tried.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EquityAotf}[Path=./Fuentes/EquityAotf/,Extension =.otf,UprightFont=*-Regular,BoldFont=*-Bold,ItalicFont=*-Italic,BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,SmallCapsFont=*-CapsRegular,Numbers=OldStyle,Kerning=On]
%\newfontfamily{\equitytab}{EquityAotfTab}
[Path=./Fuentes/EquityAotf/,Extension =.otf, UprightFont =*-Regular,BoldFont=*-Bold,Numbers=OldStyle,Kerning=On]
\usepackage[factor=1800]{microtype}

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
{\raggedright
{\makebox{\vrule width 2cm height 2mm}\hrule\vspace{1.5ex}\bfseries\huge\@title\\[1.25ex]\par}
{\large\@author}\\[1.5ex] 
{\large\@date}\\[4ex]
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[inner=17.5mm,outer=70mm,top=16.5mm,bottom=33mm,marginparwidth=43.75mm,marginparsep=8.75mm,headsep=1.5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{leading}
\leading{16.6pt}

\title{Análisis de los documentos}
\author{Rafael Benítez Mozos}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\normalfont

\section*{Introducción}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result that I get. As you can see, the lighter rule is not on the top.
[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example the code you have tried?

Comment: try to build upon `\rule[-3pt]{10em}{4pt}\rule{\dimexpr \linewidth - 10em\relax}{1pt}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the depth of rules. With `\rule`, this gives the following possibility with the dimensions in your example:

```
\rule[-2mm]{2cm}{2mm}\rule[-.4pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{.4pt}
```

MWE: (always try and reduce your MWE, i.e. remove all irrelevant packages and options)

```
\documentclass{article}
% preamble reduced to make for a real MWE

\makeatletter         
\renewcommand\maketitle{
{\raggedright
% {\makebox{\vrule width 2cm height 2mm}\hrule\vspace{1.5ex}\bfseries\huge\@title\\[1.25ex]\par} %<== removed part
{\rule[-2mm]{2cm}{2mm}\rule[-.4pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{.4pt}\par
\vspace{1.5ex}\bfseries\huge\@title\\[1.25ex]} %<-- new part
{\large\@author}\\[1.5ex] 
{\large\@date}\\[4ex]
}}
\makeatother

\title{Análisis de los documentos}
\author{Rafael Benítez Mozos}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Introducción}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive. I was trying to tweak the code that you posted on the comment, but this answer solves all my problems! Thanks a lot, Benjamin. You have helped me so much. I couldn't have finished it by myself.